# dump character stream into a single line using log4j

Tags: java, log4j

I am getting a continuous stream of characters from a ASCIIReader and I am dumping them into a file using log4j.

Is there a way to dump all the data i am getting into a single line using log4j.
For example :

output I am getting is

```
2011-12-06 09:12:28,360  INFO [main] (EAIClient.java:39) - k
2011-12-06 09:12:28,385  INFO [main] (EAIClient.java:39) - e
2011-12-06 09:12:28,386  INFO [main] (EAIClient.java:39) - e
2011-12-06 09:12:28,387  INFO [main] (EAIClient.java:39) - p
2011-12-06 09:12:28,388  INFO [main] (EAIClient.java:39) - _
2011-12-06 09:12:28,389  INFO [main] (EAIClient.java:39) - a
2011-12-06 09:12:28,391  INFO [main] (EAIClient.java:39) - l
2011-12-06 09:12:28,392  INFO [main] (EAIClient.java:39) - i
2011-12-06 09:12:28,393  INFO [main] (EAIClient.java:39) - v
2011-12-06 09:12:28,394  INFO [main] (EAIClient.java:39) - e
2011-12-06 09:12:28,396  INFO [main] (EAIClient.java:39) -
2011-12-06 09:13:28,353  INFO [main] (EAIClient.java:39) - k
```

Output I want is

Keep_Alive K

Comment: log4j.properties I am using log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender log4j.appender.R.File=log.txt    log4j.appender.R.MaxFileSize=100000KB log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=5  log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout   log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n

Comment: Post your configuration file for Log4J.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this pattern in your log4j.properties file:

```
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%m
```

This will make all in one single line without any other information like time stamp, logging level, class name and line number.